# OAuth consent screen changes not updating in marketplace listing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish an apps script as a GMAIL add-on, I have made the necessary changes to the script and the project settings, such as the OAuth consent screen, however this is not updating in the marketplace. I have deployed the newer version of the apps script and I have unpublished and republished the marketplace listing, but it does not seem to be updating the OAuth Consent Screen, see screenshots:

Store Listing:

[image]

Project OAuth consent screen settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

needed to add these OAuth to the app config in Market SDK